# Create a User with a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hey i'm making an app that has an invite system. When you are invited you receive an email allowing you to sign up as a user ***with that specific email***. So I wanted my form (invitation#show) to allow an invited person to complete registration with the exception of a email field. Being how i already know your email. But it always tells me email cannot be blank.

So I am thinking when I try to create a user(invitation#show) it always goes back to the user#create controller. Is that my problem, and if so is there any way i can change that?

**invitations controller**

```
class InvitationsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @invitation = Invitation.new
    end

  def create
  @invitation = current_user.invitations.new(params[:invitation])
    if @invitation.valid?
          temp_email = @invitation.email
        if User.find_by_email(temp_email)
          flash.now.alert = "This email was already invited!"
          render "new"
        else
          @invitation.save
          redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Invitation sent!"
          UserMailer.invitation(@invitation).deliver
      end
    else
      render "new", :notice => "Somehting went wrong!"
    end
end

 def show
    @invitation = Invitation.find_by_invite_token(params[:invite_token])
    @user.email = @invitation.email
    if @user.save 
      @user.email_activation_token = true
      cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Welcome!"
    else
      render "new", :notice => "Something went wrong!"
    end
 end

  def accept_referral
      @invitation = Invitation.find_by_invite_token(params[:invite_token])
      @invitation.accepted_at = Time.zone.now
      @invitation.save!
      if cookies[:auth_token]
        cookies.delete(:auth_token)
      end
      @user = User.new
      render "show"
  end
end
```

**users controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :admin_and_user, only: [:destory, :edit, :show]
  before_filter :admin_user, only: :index
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

**invitation#show**

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  - if @user.errors.any?
    .error_messages
      %h2 Form is invalid
      %ul
        - for message in @user.errors.full_messages
          %li
            = message
  %p
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
  %p
    = f.label :password
    = f.password_field :password
  %p
    = f.label :password_confirmation
    = f.password_field :password_confirmation

  %p.button
    = f.submit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather than handling invited user creation in separated form, maybe it's better to still use users#new and handling params[:invite_token] in it, for example:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @invitation = Invitation.find_by_invite_token(params[:invite_token]) if params[:invite_token].present?
end
```

and the form should have a hidden_field and conditions to remove email_field, for example: (in erb as I'm not comfortable with haml)

```
<% if @invitation.nil? %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
<% else %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :invite_token, @invitation.invite_token %>
<% end -%>
```

lastly, handle invite_token in users#create:

```
def create
  @invitation = Invitation.find_by_invite_token(params[:invite_token]) if params[:invite_token].present?
  params[:user][:email] = @invitation.email unless @invitation.nil?
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

you might also want to take out the @invitation code to before_filter to make things tidy and also check if @invitation.email already in use there

Comment: this looks like a good idea(hey haven't you answered my questions before lol) but I cannot get a link to user#new that keeps params[:invite_token]  i tried
redirect_to new_user_path(params[:invite_token])

Comment: yep, in fb group :)
anyway try new_user_path(invite_token: params[:invite_token])

Comment: I get "email cannot be blank"  I looked at the console and i found that @Invitation.find_by_invite_token(params[:invite_token])   is not working on user#create

Comment: check the params that received by create action, does it have correct invite_token? if not check if the new user form have invite_token hidden_field_tag with correct value..

Comment: it does have the correct invite_token actually so much so that in the user#new page i put = @invitation and got it's value

Comment: but does it sent to users#create? try adding puts(params[:invite_token].inspect) in def create and check rails s terminal also use firebug or chrome webinspector to make sure new_user form have the hidden field..

Comment: it gives nil for params[:invite_token] and the email input is not there

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32369/discussion-between-roy-and-alain-goldman)